# Python - File Handling error while using json

Tags: python, json, bash, virtualbox, file-handling

So I'm still studying python, and in the following scripts I want to do the following tasks:

1. Receive and save a file from another VM (namely VM1)
2. Convert the json string within that file into dictionary
3. Retrieve the value and then executing a bash file (namely `test.sh`) that is already in VM2

The codes are the following:

In "receiver.py"

```
import socket                 
import json
import subprocess

s = socket.socket()             
host = '10.0.2.15'
port = 60000                 

s.connect((host, port))

with open('command.py', 'wb') as f:
    print 'file opened'
    while True:
    print('receiving data...')
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    f.write(data)

f.close()
print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')

fh = open("command.py","r")
fh.read()
loaded_r = json.loads(jsonstring) 

if loaded_r['task'] == 'allow':
    subprocess.call('./test.sh')
else:
    print("not found")
```

In "command.py"

```
import json

a = {'task': 'allow'}
jsonstring = json.dumps(a)
```

When I run it, the file is received and saved on VM2, but the bash file doesn't run and I got the following error:

```
NameError: name 'jsonstring' is not defined
```

I thought `jsonstring` is already defined in `command.py`, so I don't know where to define it. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the bash script source.

Comment: Your Python code contains indentation errors. Please [edit] your question to make sure what you post is actually your runnable code. Soo also [formatting help](/help/formatting) and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to read the 'command.py' file using open. After you write the JSON. you can import it

**EX**:

```
from command import jsonstring
print jsonstring
jsonstring = json.loads(jsonstring)
```

You do not need the below step. Because it is not a JSON file. It is a python file

```
fh = open("command.py","r")
fh.read()
loaded_r = json.loads(jsonstring)
```